# angularjs ng-class in nested directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Tried so many different ways and still can't figure this. I have a menu with ng-class="{menuVisibleAnimation: menuOpen}" in a template in a nested directive. When I click on the button in the parent directive I want to change the value of menuOpen to true but the menu in the child directive is not updating?

http://plnkr.co/edit/nOunKkch0Gt8hjMWtruA?p=preview

Comment: When i click the button, the class is toggling on and off for the div: `<div class="view menuVisibleAnimation" data-ng-class="{menuVisibleAnimation: menuOpen}"><p>the view</p></div>`

Comment: The idea is that when I click on the button both the view div and <div class="menu" data-ng-class="{menuVisibleAnimation: menuOpen}" data-ng-transclude></div>. As you said, only the view div is toggling but  not the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your implementation is that you want to use the the $scope to share the value of menuOpen between the parent and child directive, but your parent directive has an **isolated** scope :

```
scope: {
  menuOpen: '@menuOpen'
}
```

You need to declare menuOpen in a scope shared by both directives, due to transclusion it has to be the parent scope of the parent directive. So, in the parent directive you should not create a new scope :

```
scope: false,
link: function($scope) {      
  $scope.menuOpen = false;
  $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
    $scope.menuOpen = !$scope.menuOpen;
  };
}
```

Then, openMenu is accessible in the child directive. See it in in a fork of your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/li5CWpVxwC08lfTVXXhV).